# sencha touch: vertical separator on toolbar

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a toolbar containing a set of buttons.
Now I want to insert a vertical separator in between these buttons.
But I am not able to find out a component in Sencha Touch which will get this for me.

Please check the below pics to get an idea of what exactly I want:

[image: Vertical separator on toolbar - 1]

[image: Vertical separator on toolbar - 2]

Please help me with this.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a work around. You can try this. First you add a button in between the button where you want to add separator like this:

```
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'plain',
                    text: '|',
                    disabled: true,
                    cls: 'separator'
                }
```

and then add style to 'separator' class like this:

```
.separator {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #6EA6CC;
}
```

Now you can customize the style according to your need.

I believe there can be better ways of doing this. Good luck.

Comment: Excellent work around :D. Looks good for now! I thought there might be a ready made component available in the Sencha Touch library.

Comment: Actually right now there is no such facility in Sencha Touch. Anyways keep exploring, who knows there is any other great work around. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid adding additional components as previously suggested, to avoid extra DOM.

This should be done in CSS/SASS, for best performance and reusability.

To mockup the above pictures, the best solution is probably to create a button style with a transparent background, a margin and a border-left property.